# Accessing data from global queue in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have about a hundred spec files that run in parallel using `parallel_rspec`. Each spec relies on a Product ID that is needed to run the spec. I want to be able to to run specs for different products each time. How can get the spec to pick a product_id from a queue, use it in the spec and put it back in the queue once done for use in another test?
Example spec:

```
describe 'Test 1' do
 let(:product) {Product.new(12345)}

  it 'checks something on the product page' do
    visit("/product/#{product.id}")
    # assert some data on the page
  end
end
```

I want to build a queue where I can store a few hundred product ids from which each example can pick one when running and put it back in the queue for other examples to use it.

I tried something like

```
class ProductPicker
  $product_ids = [1,2,3,4.....100]

  def self.pick
   product_id = $product_ids.sample
   $product_ids.delete(product_id)
  end
end
```

and then in the spec

```
let(:product) {ProductPicker.pick)}
```

This works but how can I put the product back in the queue? I need to put it back in queue because in 100 spec files I have 1000+ specs and limited products available. Another issue that there's always a chance of 2 specs running in parallel trying to access the same product from the queue. How do I make it safe for this? Open to an alternate implementation too

Comment: ""there's always a chance of 2 specs running in parallel trying to access the same product" Have you encountered this issue? I think parallel rspec uses separate instances of your test code to avoid this issue

Comment: Does it matter if 2 specs use the same product at approximately the same time? Why are you deleting the product id's at all?

Comment: @JayDorsey yes it does matter as some specs modify product state which I reset at the end of the test. If the same product is picked by another spec then the state of it will be unexpected

Comment: @LeninRajRajasekaran I have seen a few failures yes but it's only my preliminary guess that it's the reason for it. I will need to five deeper to see what's going on

Comment: @Rahul Can you share more about your setup? Are you using database cleaner/rewinder gems at all? What do you mean by "state"; as stored in the database? It sounds like your specs are heavily reliant on production data moreso than fixture/factory data. Even so, parallel spec should be using a different version of the database for each thread (if you configured it correctly) so there should be no collisions. Coupled with database rewinder/cleaner to reset the database before each run it shouldn't cause issues. Also, sounds like fixture/factory would be useful, are you using any?

Comment: @JayDorsey Thanks. The tests are run against a .Net application and run out of process. Not using any DBs what so ever. All tests do is visit a product page(all I have on me is a list of product IDs imported into the system externally) and add/update data using forms on the page and assert some expectations. The main thing here is we want to run these tests against many different products.

Comment: @Rahul you might be able to `shuffle` your product ids' global var when you initialize it so you have a consistent order, rather than sampling, then `shift ` values off and  `push` them back on with your class. If the array is big enough you shouldn't run into issues as long as the state is setup across the parallel rspec threads